# Batch resizing with ImageMagick's mpr and spawn in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, spawn

I am currently converting PDFs into multiple JPGs in different dimensions with ImageMagick installed in Google Cloud Functions with Node.js.

I do it in a `Promise.all()` call like this:

```
return Promise.all([
  spawn("convert", [
    sourceFilePathTemp,
    "-resize",
    `1600x`,
    `${imageDirTemp}/image-large-%03d.jpg`,
  ]),
  spawn("convert", [
    sourceFilePathTemp,
    "-resize",
    `800x`,
    `${imageDirTemp}/image-medium-%03d.jpg`,
  ]),
  spawn("convert", [
    sourceFilePathTemp,
    "-thumbnail",
    `200x200>`,
    `${imageDirTemp}/image-thumbnail-%03d.jpg`,
  ]),
]);
```

I have realized I can do these 3 calls in just one call according to the ImageMagick using `mpr` (=memory program register) (https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpr).

The documentation holds an example of resizing an image into multiple dimensions:

```
convert scroll.gif  -background lightsteelblue -flatten  -alpha off \
        -write mpr:scroll  -resize x128  -write scroll_lrg.jpg +delete \
                mpr:scroll  -resize x96   -write scroll_big.jpg +delete \
                mpr:scroll  -resize x64   -write scroll_med.jpg +delete \
                mpr:scroll  -resize x32          scroll_sml.jpg
```

However, I don't know how to write this command with `spawn`.

I guess it would be something like the following, but I don't know how to group the elements in the options array and in which order when the commands get complex

```
  spawn("convert", [
    sourceFilePathTemp,
    "-write",
    `mpr:file -resize x128 -write ${imageDirTemp}/image-large-%03d.jpg +delete`,
    `mpr:file -resize x96 -write ${imageDirTemp}/image-medium-%03d.jpg +delete`,
    `mpr:file -resize x64 -write ${imageDirTemp}/image-small-%03d.jpg +delete`,
  ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

Each separate argument to `convert` should be its own array element.  If you separated it by a space from the other arguments, then it should be its own list element.  For example:

```
[sourceFilePathTemp, "-write", "mpr:file", "-resize", "x128", ...]
```

And so on, for each argument.